# Error occurred while registering a new user in the database (in ASP.NET Core 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I use the following function, I get an error. Does anyone know what I should do?

```cs
public Guid GetRoleByName(string name)
{
    return _context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == name).Id;
}
```

I get this error when trying to add a new user to the database:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object. Snapp.Core.Services.AccountService.GetRoleByName(string
> name) in AccountService.cs, line 72

[image: error]

Please let me know if the coding style has changed (:

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering this error because SingleOrDefault() is returning NULL. If you try and do .Id on a null object...then you will encounter the error that you described. I would change your code to do the following:

```cs
    public Role GetRoleByName(string name)
    {
        return _context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == name);
    }
```

When you call this method, you should be defensive with your approach:

```cs
    var role = GetRoleByName("Admin");

    if (role != null)
    {
      ...
    }
```

Comment: It's 2024 now, plese update your answer to use C# nullable annotations.

Comment: Agreed…I just wanted to illustrate what was wrong in a simple manner that was easy to read / understand.